# vue i18 how to truncate currency?

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I would like to truncate a currency so it won't overflow out of my div.
I couldn't find anything besides

```
minimumFractionDigits: 0,
maximumFractionDigits: 1,
minimumSignificantDigits: 2,
maximumSignificantDigits: 3
```

but for some reason it doesn't work for my currencies only for the percentages

code example with a ridicolus number that will break the layout.

```
<div class="col-span-12 lg:col-span-12 text-right order-2 lg:order-1">
   {{ $n(777724712742172132132144721, "currency") }}
</div>
```

is there a way to overcome it from i18 point of view or rather style/truncate the container?

Comment: What is your desired output? If you truncate the number, it would be a whole different number...

Comment: simply put i need to make sure that the amount of currency will not overflow from the container using the best practices of course.

in my head and ellipsis should be appended when the value reach a certain amount
i.e
777724712742172132132... USD

I'm also open to suggestions.

Comment: It's rarely a good idea at all to truncate an integer, anything like isn't related to i18n. Probably you just need text-overflow:ellipsis style

Comment: already tried it. unfortunately it truncate the currency symbol.

that leads to 777724712742172132132... instead of something like 777724712742172132132... USD

Comment: In order not to lose information about the number (since truncating does exactly that) you can convert it toExponential and display as much info as you like. this way you lose only precision. For ex. `n.toExponential(10) // 7.7772471274e+26`

Comment: I'd take another approach: If you are writing code for a UI that is going to be used by others, then I'd start by working out what is acceptable display for certain extreme use cases and then code to that. Don't forget a good UI provides good UX, so consider the humans and not just the programmers.